# How to create selectable lists in tabs

Tags: flutter, dart

How to create selectable lists on different tabs?

I am trying to listen to selection mode from `ValueNotifier`. Can't use states because rebuilding whole thing is expensive, and `ValueNotifier` provides a handy `child` property allowing not to rebuild entirely.

I need to be able to call list methods from parent. `ValueNotifier` is initialized in child's `initState` method with items of the current tab.

The problem is when I *start* dragging tab then release it, thus staying in the current tab, the other tab still builds, it's `initState` is called and `ValueNotifier` gets rewritten. Then when method from parent is called it gets the wrong items list from currently still active tab.

Simplified example:

```
    class Home extends StatelessWidget {
      Home({super.key});
    
      late int Function() showListLength;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
        const List tabs = [
          Tab(text: 'First'),
          Tab(text: 'Second')
        ];
    
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            actions: [
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () => (){
                  SnackBar snackBar = SnackBar(
                    content: Text('List length is ${showListLength.call()}'),
                  );
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
                }(),
                child: const Text('Show list length')
              )
            ],
          ),
          body: DefaultTabController(
            length: tabs.length,
            child: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context){
              return Column(
                children: [
                  const TabBar(tabs: tabs),
                  child: TabBarView(
                    children: tabs.map(
                      (Tab tab) => MyTab(
                        tab: tab.text!,
                        builder: (
                          BuildContext context,
                          int Function() methodFromChild,
                        ) {
                          showListLength = methodFromChild;
                        }
                      )
                    ).toList(),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            }),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class MyTab extends StatefulWidget {
    
      final String tab;
      final MyBuilder builder;
    
      const MyTab({super.key, required this.tab, required this.builder});
    
      @override
      State createState() => MyTabState();
    }
    
    class MyTabState extends State {
    
      late final List list;
      late final ValueNotifier> selected;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        list = widget.tab == 'First'
          ? List.generate(5, (index) => index)
          : List.generate(10, (index) => index);
        selected = ValueNotifier>(list);
    
        super.initState();
      }
    
      int showSelectedLength() => selected.value.length;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
        widget.builder.call(context, showSelectedLength);
    
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: list.length,
          itemBuilder: (_,index){
            return Text(index.toString());
          });
      }
    }
```

[image]

Complete copy/paste example here: https://pastebin.com/kzu2vuPk